# how to Reference the variable via db.run_in_transaction on google-app-engine 

Tags: python, google-app-engine, transactions

this is my code:

```
class A(db.Model):
    a=db.StringProperty()

class demo(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        a=''
        def fn():
            global a
            a=A(a='www')
            a.put()
        db.run_in_transaction(fn)
        raise Exception(a.key())
```

and  the error is :

```
raise Exception(a.key())
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'key'
```

so how to get the right 'a' ,

thanks

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
class demo(BaseRequestHandler):
    def get(self):
        def fn():
            a=A(a='www')
            a.put()
            return a
        a = db.run_in_transaction(fn)
        raise Exception(a.key())
```